# Derivative of a potential when deriving Boltzmann equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, boltzmann-equation

Consider a system with $N$ identical particles of mass $m$, whose coordinates and momenta are $(q_i,p_i)$, $i = 1,\ldots,N$, and with Hamiltonian
$$
H=\sum_{j=1}^N \frac{p_j^2}{2m} + \sum_{1\leq j < k \leq N} V(|\vec{q}_j-\vec{q}_k|)
$$

I have an issue with evaluation of the momentum equation $\dot{\vec{p}_i}$. If I write the $\frac{\partial H}{\partial \vec{q}_i}$, where I am using the partial notation instead of nabla, explicitly, i get:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial H}{\partial \vec{q}_i} &= \frac{\partial }{\partial \vec{q}_i}\sum_{1\leq j < k \leq N} V(|\vec{q}_j-\vec{q}_k|) = \frac{\partial }{\partial \vec{q}_i}\sum_{k=2}^N \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} V(|\vec{q}_j-\vec{q}_k|) \\
&=\sum_{k=2}^N \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \frac{\partial }{\partial \vec{q}_i}V(|\vec{q}_j-\vec{q}_k|)
\end{align}
$$

However, unless i am missing something, one has to do the derivative as:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial V(|\vec{q}_j-\vec{q}_k|)}{\partial \vec{q}_i} &= \frac{\partial V(|\vec{q}_j-\vec{q}_k|)}{\partial \vec{q}_i}\delta_{ij} + \frac{\partial V(|\vec{q}_j-\vec{q}_k|)}{\partial \vec{q}_i}\delta_{ik}
\end{align}
$$

This is because the derivatives are not the same (have opposite sign).

The problem is that the correct results should be:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial H}{\partial \vec{q}_i} &= \sum_{k\neq i}\frac{\partial V(|\vec{q}_i-\vec{q}_k|)}{\partial \vec{q}_i}
\end{align}
$$

I have no idea how to get this result. What am i doing incorrectly?

---

**Note:**

One comes across this problem e.g. when deriving the Boltzman kinetic equation in plasma from the Liouville's equation when one wants to switch from the $N$ particle density distribution function to the reduced one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that, once you plug the derivative into the summation, the result should follow after some algebraic manipulations. It may help to write the summation in the Hamiltonian as
$$\sum_{1\leq j < k \leq N} = 
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^N\sum_{k=1, k\neq j}^N,$$
sinc ethe potential is symmetric in respect to interchanging $q_j$ and $q_k$.

Comment: I thought about this but what about $\partial_i V_{ij} \neq \partial_i V_{ji}$ that is while the potential is symmetrical with respect to interchanging the particles, the derivative is not. Or not?

Comment: I think it is symmetric. Note also that the sum contains both $V_{ij}$ and $V_{ji}$

Comment: @leosenko and derivative in your question is symmetric: $\partial_i V_{jk}=\partial_i V_{kj}$